# Convert JavaScript Popup to Alert Box

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have the following code in a PHP page. The code below was converted from a popup window to open in the same window. I need to convert it so that instead of going to a new page, it outputs the request.php result as a standard Javascript alert box. I have seen it done before with this same type of setup, I just haven't been able to get mine to work.

The server is running PHP 5.1.6 and cannot be updated by me (Provided by university), so certain PHP functions are unavailable. I'm not whether or not that is helpful information.

The page returns:

```
Request Status
Thank you for your request, it has been added to the queue.
```

or:

```
Request Status
You can only submit a request once per 300 seconds.
```

The current PHP code is below:

```
$ret = "<a href=\ "#\" onClick=\ "javascript:window.open('request.php?id=".$params[ 'id']. "','_self','scrollbars=yes,status=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizeable=yes,height=200,width=400'); return false;\"><img src=\"";
```

Comment: what is jQuery alert box ? plus, the PHP codes contain error, and the HTML codes have multiple problems. last, alert box & javascript are client-side scripting, while PHP is server-side scripting. PHP version should not bother your alert.

Comment: Are you talking about a jQuery UI Dialog widget? That's the closest I can think of to a jQuery alert box. Or are you just talking about the standard Javascript function `alert("message")`?

Comment: @Barmar, The standard Javascript alert box, I believe. I just looked up the difference between them (again). I got the two confused somewhere down the line.

Comment: @Raptor, to what errors are you referring? That code works without error in the full php file.

Comment: Where does the message that it should display in the alert box come from?

Comment: PHP: extra space after backslash. HTML: use of old-fashioned camel-case `onClick` , use `#` in `href` (this will make the page jump to top), truncated `<img>` tags, etc.

Comment: It looks like you need to write code that uses AJAX to call `request.php`, scrape the error message out of the response, and then display that in the `alert()` box.

Comment: @Barmar, the message would come from the request.php file

Comment: I got it to dump the php output to the alert box, but I need to strip the HTML tags from it. Any ideas?

Comment: I got the alert box working, but it dumps the entire page in html tags to the alert box. How can I strip the HTML tags out of it (or should I ask a new question?)

Answer (score 1):

I got this (kind of) working by changing the line

```
$ret = "<a href=\ "#\" onClick=\ "javascript:window.open('request.php?id=".$params[ 'id']. "','_self','scrollbars=yes,status=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizeable=yes,height=200,width=400'); return false;\"><img src=\"";
```

to

```
$ret = "<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"javascript:jQuery.get('request.php?id=".$params['id']."', function(data) { alert(data); });\"><img src=\"";
```

however, this dumps the entire page (including html tags) to the alert box.